# Индексирование поисковыми системами приложения на React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Понравился компонентный подход в реализации React js, но столкнулся с проблемой, страница, которая рендерится при помощи javascript не индексируется поисковыми системами (гуглом только, яндекс индексирует как пустую). Погуглил, и единственное что нашел - это рендеринг на сервере или изоморфное приложение (возможно это одно и тоже, не до конца понял), но скомпилировать на сервере и отдать уже отренедеренный html шаблон, насколько я понял, возможно только при помощи nodejs. Возможно ли как-то сделать пререндер без nodejs ? Или какими путями можно еще решить проблему с индексированием ?

Comment: Про индексацию таких сайтов: [Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/robot-workings/ajax-indexing.xml) и [Google](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)

Comment: @sanu0074 автор спрашивает как сделать рендер на сервере без ноды, ссылка на "а вы сделайте рендер на сервере" не слишком поможет

Comment: посмотри `prerender.io` если у тебя ест доступ к серверу и его конфигурированию

Comment: Просто оставляйте серверные страницы, а на клиенте перерисовываете их по запросу, зачем вам сложности?

Answer (score 1):

На момент 2018 года, SPA сайты индексируются Google и Yandex, хотя провайдеры отмечают что боты могут рендерить страницу не правильно или же не рендерить вовсе, а также существует вероятность что ранжирование будет не в пользу SPA.

Пререндер нужен для очень тонких настроек SEO, или же в том случае когда нужно достигать первых позиций выдачи в поисковике "естественным образм". Если же таковые не планируются, то самое главное правльная организация роутинга и локализации приложения.